# Android custom gui-components?

Tags: android, android-library, android-gui

Im searching for an android gui-library with more components i could use in my app.

Example:

A microcontroller sends the rpm of a motor (via bluetooth) to my smartphone.
And i want to use my smartphone in order to show the received rpm in progressbar-like element.
But the normal progressbar looks ugly, and i would have to progressbar.setClickable(false); .

As i said before
Im searching a library with more gui-elements(optional: i could modify, customize the outward appearance on my own)

Do anybody of you know about such a library ?

Thanks so far.

Answer (score 0):

If you're just concerned about the external appearance of your GUI elements, I don't think there's any support for *different* UI elements than the ones provided. However, have you looked into a universal [`Theme` and style for your application](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)?

Here are some excerpts from that document:

> A style is a collection of properties that specify the look and format
>   for a View or window. A style can specify properties such as height,
>   padding, font color, font size, background color, and much more. A
>   style is defined in an XML resource that is separate from the XML that
>   specifies the layout.
>
> A theme is a style applied to an entire Activity or application,
>   rather than an individual View (as in the example above). When a style
>   is applied as a theme, every View in the Activity or application will
>   apply each style property that it supports. For example, you can apply
>   the same CodeFont style as a theme for an Activity and then all text
>   inside that Activity will have green monospace font.

Here are some resources which talk about themes:

- [Mobile Orchard Article](http://mobileorchard.com/android-app-development-using-themes-and-styles-in-android/)
- [Android Engineer Article](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-themes-in-android-applications.html)

Let me know if that's what you wanted. Themes give you almost *infinite possibilities* to modify outwards appearance.